# Cusomizing tooltip Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

The different appearance of the tooltip is

[image]

[image]

How to customize the tooltip in Bootstrap.
How do I style the tooltip so that the edges start immediately below the icon that was pointed?

Comment: I've just done some tests and found that padding pushes the Tooltip away. I am convince that you just need to adjust padding to get what you want.

Comment: If will be helpful if  you share your code..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7rows/zwqbL0y9/13/
this example